How do I accurately recreate the ER effect (using electro-rheological fluid)?
I am working on a project that makes use of the unique properties of electro-rheological fluid (ERF), a substance that changes viscosity when an electric field is applied:

For this project, I want to create a way to accurately recreate this effect at home for a video, clearly showing the change in viscosity before and after the application of an electric field.
However, I am a high school student and my skills in working with electric components are limited. I have the resources necessary to purchase electric components but not the expertise to understand how to make an electric circuit that accomplishes the task.
Here is what I have understood from my research:

I need some way to create a large potential difference (~400V) over two conductive plates, between which the ERF is placed.
I need a component which can both amplify and regulate the voltage between the two plates (something like this product I found online)

Here is what I have done so far:

I have built a primitive version of what I need that uses two pieces of folded aluminum foil in a small insulated can, with each piece connected by wire to a power source of 3V. I tested that the system worked by placing an LED between the plates, and it was lit. Then I put ERF into the can, and observed no difference in the viscosity of the substance when voltage was applied (assumption: voltage is way to small to change the viscosity). Here is a diagram I made of what I put together:


I would appreciate any assistance, advice, or recommendations for components to use and how to such a circuit together in a way that allows me to accurately depict the change in viscosity of an ERF using an electric field.
